# Activate or deactivate button with CheckButton

Tags: python, tkinter, activation

I created this program, but I would like the button "button" (first part) 
to be deactivated if we don't select checkButton (second part). So I would like to activate the button only if CheckButton is selected.

```
acceptButton = IntVar()
case = Checkbutton(fenetre, text="I accept the agreement", variable=acceptButton, cursor="hand2", bg="white",)
case.pack()
var = case.select() == 1

doNotButton = IntVar()
case2 = Checkbutton(fenetre, text="I do not accept the agreement", variable=doNotButton, bg="white", state=DISABLED) #il est impossible de cocher cette case
case2.pack()
```

the button:

```
button = Button(fenetre, text="Suivant", command=commandSuiv, cursor="hand2", height=1, width = 15) #taille
button.pack()
button.place(x=c, y=d)
button.configure(font=f)
```

Thank you so much
:)

Comment: Salut Antonin! Please change your question to English language as described in our guidelines on: [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In this way your quesiton will be reachable for more people in the community. Merci!

Comment: Read [When to use the Radiobutton Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can first check the CheckButton variable, then accordingly set the state of the Button:

```
if acceptButton.get() == 0: # Your binded var returns 0 if unchecked, 1 otherwise
    button.config(state="disabled")
```

You also could reverse the process by disabling the button by default, it would probably be more elegant:

```
button = Button(fenetre, text="Suivant", command=commandSuiv, cursor="hand2", height=1, width = 15, state=DISABLED) #taille
```

Then to enable it, it would be:

```
if acceptButton.get() == 1:
    button.config(state="normal")
```

Comment: Without a callback from either `Checkbutton`'s or `<IntVar ref>.trace(...`, your example will not work.

Comment: thank you.. but dont' work :/
if i write 
```var = case.select() == 1```
it's good. so if i deselect, the button don't change.